# Creating multiple IoC containers

Tags: java, spring

I know I can create multiple IoC containers programtically like this:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
ApplicationContext applicationContext2 = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
```

But if I do below then will I get 2 IoC containers, or is it that I can create 2 IoC container programatically but cannot cerate it decoratively as shown below. I am not able to verify this.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/twiApplication-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/twiApplication-servlet2.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

If above doesn't create 2 IoC container, then how I can create 2 IoC containers decoratively?

Answer (score 0):

One ApplicationContext (a.k.a IoC Container) gets its data from one XML-file. when you want to have two different IoC-Containers, you need to have two different XML-files.

And you have the same param-name (contextConfigLocation) for both param-values.

Comment: If that doesn't create 2 IoC container, then how I can create 2 IoC containers decoratively?